# How to print to a specific scale with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography

How can I print a map with QGIS to a specific scale? E.g. I have a  map of Austria (projection: Albers equal area) and want a printout on paper at 1: 3000000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you add the "map" object in the composer, select item, enter the "item" tab and select the scale you want.

Comment: Giovanni, thank you very much . I works fine (I was trying to do the job via the scale-bar )